# Delete item from pinia state

Tags: vue.js, vuex, pinia

I am new to vue and I have just started using `pinia`. I wanna delete an item from `array` but it does not work

here is my store

```
import {defineStore} from 'pinia'

export interface ObjectDto {
  input: string,
}

interface ObjectDtoInterface {
  objects: Array<ObjectDto>
}

export const useSearchHistoryStore = defineStore('objectsStore', {
  state: (): ObjectDtoInterface => {
    return {
      objects: [] as ObjectDto[]
    }
  },
  actions: {
    add(dto: ObjectDto) {
      if (this.objects
        .filter(shd => dto.input === shd.input)
        .length === 0) {
        this.objects.unshift(dto)
      }
    },
    delete(obj: ObjectDto) {
      this.objects = this.objects.filter(e => !(e.input === obj.input))
    }
  }
})
```

and here is the function from different `.ts` file

```
function delete(obj: ObjectDto) {
  objectsStore.delete(obj)
}
```

`add` action works perfect, it adds item to the state but when I try to `delete` an item, nothing happens. The data I pass to `delete` method is 100% good because I checked this many times

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. Either that, or `splice`. Both are ok. There is nothing in your code that could explain why this happens. Probably you're misusing a store and keep a reference to `objects`

Answer (score 1):

Filter does not mutate the original object, you need to reasing

```
delete(obj: ObjectDto) {
      this.objects = this.objects.filter(e => !(e.input === obj.input))
 }
```

more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: nah, already tried it, its my fault to not adding this into the code snippet (tried many versions and forgot to add this back)
and this not work